# Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: php, .htaccess

**403 FORBIDDEN**

You don't have permission to `access/folder_name/index.php` on this server.

Server unable to read `.htaccess` file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request.

Here is *.htaccess* code:

```
<Files 403.shtml> 
order allow,
deny allow from all 
</Files>
```

And I also tried another code:

```
<Directory "/path/to/source/file/directory/www"> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride all 
Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

But I am confused on the line "path/to/source/file/directory/www".

Comment: Please provide your `.htaccess` code

Comment: Additionally, ensure the webserver can actually read the htaccess file, as it says it can't. Ensure the permissions are `rw-rw-r--` (`chmod 644 .htaccess`) or some variation, and ensure the user/group Apache is running under has access to that file/directory, assuming you're hosting on Linux.

Comment: This is my .htaccess code #<Files 403.shtml> order allow,deny allow from all </Files> and i tried another code <Directory "/path/to/source/file/directory/www"> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride all Require all granted </Directory> but i am confused on the line "path/to/source/file/directory/www" –

Answer (score 41):

Make sure that the `.htaccess` file is readable by `apache`:

```
chmod 644 access/folder_name/.htaccess
```

And make sure the directory which contains `.htaccess` is readable and executable:

```
chmod 755 access/folder_name/
```

Comment: In my case the directory was set 750, then chmoded to 755 and it worked.

Comment: @DakshShah On the server, where the web is hosted. You should have your FTP credentials available in hosting overview.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `cpanel`, then go to the public `HTML` folder or else which subfolder creating the problem.
right click the folder, you get the option, change permission.
 make alternative changes accordingly so you can make live your web page 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am on rackspeed and use cpanel. I created a subdomain which also created the base folder. But I deleted the base folder and created it again, which caused the error.

I had to open the subdomain configuration and edit the base directory. The correct base directory was already entered but I had to do It again nevertheless, to make it reinitialize.